# Euclidean distance between RGB histogram of two images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, histogram, euclidean-distance

I have two pictures with histogram of the R,G,B intensities for each image. I am suppose to find the euclidean distance using the values of histogram to find the similarity.

I know euclidean distance formula is:

```
= sqr((R1-R2)^2 +(G1-G2)^2+(B1-B2)^2)
```

Since the histogram of R G and B for each image has several values, so are you suppose to take the average of all the intensity values in one histogram and then subtract it with the average of intensity values of the other histogram?

**Example 1:**

```
Image1: R1 histogram has values of 2,3,4 
Image2: R2 histogram has values of 2,3,1
```

1. Then do I do `R1=(2+3+4)/3 ,R2=(2+3+1)/3`
2. Then do I do `(9-6)^2` for the value `(R1-R2)^2` in `sqr((R1-R2)^2+(G1-G2)^2+(B1-B2)^2)`?

**OR**

**Example 2:**

```
Image1: R1 histogram has values of 2,3,4 
Image2: R2 histogram has values of 2,3,1
```

1. Then do I do this `(2-2)^2 +(3-3)^2 +(4-1)^2` for the `(R1-R2)^2` in `sqr((R1-R2)^2 +(G1-G2)^2+(B1-B2)^2)`?

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: RGB colors are not related to each other with euclidean distance. i.e. the euclidean distance between 2 RGB values has nothing to do with how close we humans we perceive those colors to be. If you want to compare colors (e.g. find the closest color to a particular color), then you need to use the [`L*a*b*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) color space.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: the question is about histogram distances. It has little to do with color comparison and human perception.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a histogram as a vector (maybe there are 256 bins, so it’s a 256-dimensional vector). Now compute the Euclidean distance between the two vectors:

```
DR = norm(R1-R2); % same as sqrt(sum((R1-R2).^2))
```

You can repeat this for each R, G and B component, and combine the three distances again using the Euclidean norm:

```
D = sqrt(DR.^2 + DG.^2 + DB.^2);
```

This is the same as concatenating the 3 color histograms for each image and computing their distance:

```
H1 = [R1,G1,B1]; % assuming histograms are row vectors
H2 = [R2,G2,B2];
D = norm(H1-H2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mixing Normalization with Euclidean Distance.

```
Euclidean Distance = Sqrt( Sum( ( a[i][j] - b[i][j] )^2 ) ) for all i = 0..width, j = 0..height
```

a[][] and b[][] can be normalized data or non-normalized data. If you are using the raw image pixel values, they are non-normalized. You can normalize the images by dividing by the intensity range of the pixel values (min-max normalization).

So, compute the normalized images anorm[][] and bnorm[][] in the first pass where,

```
for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    anorm[i][j] = a[i][j] / (max_a - min_a);
    bnorm[i][j] = b[i][j] / (max_b - min_b);
  }
}
```

Now, apply the Euclidean Distance formula on anorm[][] and bnorm[][].

Comment: See: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=422994DDDEE5D01D4B4340533A5034CF?doi=10.1.1.680.2097&rep=rep1&type=pdf

for a definition of Image Euclidean Distance (ref. Eqn (1))

Comment: @Cris Luengo: You are right about the normalization. I have changed the above to refer to min-max normalization transform which will convert the pixel values to the range 0 to 1.

Comment: I’ll remove my downvote then. But I object to calling that distance “Euclidean”. In this paper they clearly state that their distance does not satisfy the triangle inequality, which is an important characteristic of the Euclidean distance. They should have named their method differently, calling a new distance measure by the well known name of the most basic, important distance measure is confusing at best. Nevertheless, that paper seems to have an interesting idea buried somewhere, I will read it in more detail and revisit your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Luengo: I am treating the image as a vector of dimension MxN. With that context, the calculation is the textbook Euclidean distance of two vectors.

Comment: The question is about distance between histograms, while you reply with the SSD similarity metric. Irrelevant.