# Calculating Distances Between 2 Histograms by Using Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram, opencv

I am trying to calculate euclidean distances of two hue image histograms, I have found cv2.compareHist method but it does not give an option for euclidean distance. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: see higher dimensions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance. Each bin is a different dimension

Comment: i am very bad at maths, so i must ask will the result be a number, or an array of numbers

Comment: have you seen this? [Euclidean distance between RGB histogram of two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579933/euclidean-distance-between-rgb-histogram-of-two-images)

Comment: A single number: `dist=sqrt( ( (bin1a-bin1b)^2 ... (bin256a-bin256b) ) / 256)`, where bin1a in the first bin count of imageA and bin1b is first bin count of imageB, etc. That is the distance is the square root of the average of the squares of the difference between corresponding bins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import math

# Load the images
img1 = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('zelda1.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Calculate the histograms, and normalize them
hist1 = cv2.calcHist([gray1], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
#cv2.normalize(hist1, hist1, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

hist2 = cv2.calcHist([gray2], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
#cv2.normalize(hist2, hist2, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# compute euclidean distance
sum = 0
for i in range (0,256):
    sum = sum + (hist1[i][0]-hist2[i][0])**2
dist = math.sqrt(sum)
print('euclidean distance:', dist)

# above is equivalent to cv2.norm()
dist2 = cv2.norm(hist1, hist2, normType=cv2.NORM_L2)
print('euclidean distance2:', dist2)
```

Results:

```
euclidean distance : 2319.6163475885405
euclidean distance2: 2319.6163475885405
```

If the images do not have the same dimensions (total pixels=width*height), then one probably should normalize the histograms by dividing every bin by the total pixels in the image.

Comment: Shouldn't it be equal to `dist = cv2.norm(hist1, hist2)`? Why are you dividing the sum by 256?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, I was thinking rmse. I did not know about cv2.norm().

Comment: I have corrected my post accordingly to comment from @rotem.